# first_or_create not saving one column or attribute postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql, pg

folks.

When issuing the following code block in the controller, the resulting SQL does not include one column/attr of the model:

```
dev_total = DeviceTotal.where(time_stamp: @time_stamp).first_or_create {|dt|
    dt.dev_utc = @utc,
    dt.value = @grand_total, 
    dt.production = @net_weight,
    dt.device_id = @device.id,
    dt.var = @device.variable.symbol
}
```

Resulting SQL:

```
INSERT INTO "device_totals" ("created_at", "device_id", "production", "time_stamp",
"updated_at", "value", "var") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) 
RETURNING "id"      [["created_at", Wed, 09 Oct 2013 22:54:04 UTC +00:00],
["device_id", 1], ["production",     80.38], ["time_stamp", Wed, 09 Oct 2013 22:53:59
UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Wed, 09 Oct     2013 22:54:04 UTC +00:00], ["value",
847.25], ["var", "FRL"]]
```

As one can see, the column 'dev_utc' is not included in the INSERT command. All other attributes are saved to the DB. This is a BigInt type column.

Everything else works fine.
Checked my code dozens of times w/o any luck.

Any clues?

Comment: Your insert query contains column name time_stamp but it is not in code except where.

Comment: Sorry. Actually this column (time_stamp) gets saved properly; the problem is about the "dev_utc" column. Weird.

Comment: I have also tried this in insert query the value of `dev_utc` column is null but i was able to update that column with same value which i have passed in insert query

Comment: Still no good. This is weird, for sure. Thanks for your interest,

Comment: Change `first_or_create` to `first_or_create!` and see if it raises any errors

Comment: Please show us the code for `DeviceTotal`. Are you using any `attr_accessor` or something like that?

Comment: Sorry, no attr_accessor. And sorry for being away. Still, I cannot make the proposed test yet. Should be back to the project on next week. TIA